# Determine which Delaunay edge is Gabriel

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, delaunay

My purpose is to implement the algorithm to check whether a Delaunay edge is Gabriel.

As the definition, a Delaunay triangulation edge is said to be a Gabriel edge if its diametrical circle is empty. So, to check whether it is a Gabriel edge or not, we need to *scan through all finite vertices in Delaunay to check if any is in that diametrical circle* OR we just need to *check on its 2 adjacent triangles*. Which is the accurate option?

Comment: The adjacent two vertices is sufficient, you certainly don't need to check every vertex in the graph. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_graph). Performance to convert a Delaunay Triangulation to it's Gabriel graph should be O(N).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check the two adjacent triangles. Suppose the third vertex on one of the neighboring triangles is not inside the diametral ball of an edge (i.e., it suggests that the edge may have the Gabriel property). The empty (by the Delaunay property) circumcircle of this triangle (dashed below) contains a semi-circle corresponding to the Gabriel ball (in gray below). If you check both Delaunay triangles attached to an edge, you know that both halves of the Gabriel ball are empty.

[image]